# 'is' not @JsonIgnore-d

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, lombok

With Lombok 1.18.12 and Jackson 2.11.0, this POJO:

```
@Data @NoArgsConstructor
private static class MyPojo {
    private Long id = 1L;
    private boolean isGood = true;
    @JsonIgnore
    private boolean isIgnored = false;

}
```

does not ignore the `isIgnored` field so the test fails:

```
@Test
public void serializePojo() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
    String actualJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);
    String expectedJson = "{\"id\":1,\"good\":true}";

    assertThat(actualJson).asString().isEqualToIgnoringWhitespace(expectedJson);
}
```

because the actual JSON is:

```
JSON{"id":1,"ignored":false,"good":true}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add `@JsonIgnore` to an explicit getter:

```
@Data @NoArgsConstructor
private static class MyPojo {
    private Long id = 1L;
    private boolean isGood = true;
    private boolean isIgnored = true;

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isIgnored() {
        return isIgnored;
    }

}
```

A work-around is to avoid the (common) `is` prefix on boolean properties:

```
@Data @NoArgsConstructor
private static class MyPojo {
    private Long id = 1L;
    private boolean isGood = true;
    @JsonIgnore
    private boolean ignored = true;

}
```